# Selecting objects in a list of lists

Tags: c#, linq

This is above my skill level in Linq, so I'm turning here for help. This code works but I think it could run a lot faster and take up less room.

```
private List<DateTime> GetUniqueTimeStamps()
{
    List<DateTime> timeStamps = new List<DateTime>();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Instrument> kvp in Instruments)
    {
        foreach (Bar bar in kvp.Value.Bars)
        {
            timeStamps.Add(bar.Time);
        }
    }

    return timeStamps.Distinct().ToList();
}
```

How can I use linq to skip all the loops and jump down the object properties to get the unique DateTime values?

Comment: FWIW, you simplify your code with linq, but it doesnt mean you're actually skipping loops.  Linq just handles them for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to flatten the lists, then [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to get the times:

```
Instruments.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value.Bars).Select(b => b.Time).Distinct().ToList();
```

Note that this isn't any more efficient (you aren't even taking advantage of lazy enumeration due to the `ToList`). It is shorter and a bit easier to read however.

Comment: Don't forget the `.Distinct()` as in the question.

Comment: Thanks. I need to get more familiar with all the linq methods beyond Select and Where. Does anyone know a good linq tutorial? I'm currently learning the hard way.